# Bash/perl script to verify kerberos principals password

Tags: perforce, kerberos

I'm trying to write a script which takes a username via argument and password via stdin. I'd like the script to contact the kerberos server and verify the password. I'm going to use this to authenticate perforce users via an auth-check trigger. I'm not too wedded to any particular language although bash and perl are already installed on the (centos 5) system concerned.

Any hints/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Fenster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just come across [pwauth](http://code.google.com/p/pwauth/wiki/Risks) on google code. It can be configured to verify system passwords using the pam interface. It looks like its been designed with apache in mind but should work for any scriptable situation. Going to try and set this up this week. Will report back when i've tried it.

NB there are risks with exposing your system accounts so the link directs you to the risks page first.

Answer (score 1):

This Perforce article has some useful links to get started.

http://kb.perforce.com/article/74

I think Kerberos saves a ticket on the machine you're authenticating on, so perhaps Perforce's SSO framework would be better.  Check out this project:

http://www.assembla.com/spaces/sso-p4/wiki

Comment: I've followed the guide and proven the triggers concept. SSO is undesirable for a few reasons: we use jenkins for continuous integration which i don't believe supports perforce sso, sso would require reconfiguration of all client machines rather than just the server. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that effectively verifying a password requires more than just doing kinit (an AS exchange). That is open to a KDC spoofing attack: the attacker hands you a password, then redirects your KDC request to his own KDC which says the password is OK.

The usual way to guard against this is for the verifier to have a service principal of its own; it kinits the user's principal, then uses the acquired TGT to obtain a service ticket for its own principal and verifies that ticket. This ensures that it is talking to the same KDC.